# MinGW missing make?

Tags: windows, mingw, gnu-make

my windows travis-ci build failed, it appears that the command `make` is not in the `PATH`? see log [here](https://travis-ci.com/github/fangq/mmc/builds/176816501).

*Does the mingw package installed by default include make?* appreciated if someone can point to me an example configuration that use make/gcc to compile on windows. My `.travis.yml` can be found [here](https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Comment: Most MinGW have a `mingw32-make.exe` file but no `make.exe`. Simply copy and rename it or change the call from make to mingw32-make.

Comment: thanks, yes, I realized that after a little bit googling, and it is now working

Answer (score 1):

Most MinGW have a `mingw32-make.exe` file but no `make.exe`. Simply copy that and rename it or change the call from `make` to `mingw32-make` in your build.